# How do you format a html file for a4 size print?

Tags: html, css, pdf

I'm trying to convert a html file to pdf. I have a responsive resume to show on the web but I also need a downloadable pdf version placed neatly on x2 A4 sized sheets, so that I'm able to apply for work. I have tried the '@media print' query but print format & PDF conversion seem to be overriding the layout.

I would really appreciate any guidance with this, and forgive me for the simplicity of the question. I'm new to the club but learning fast!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For us to help you better, actually provide a [MCVE] of what you have tried and provide a more detailed description of how your attempt is not meeting your expectations.

Comment: If you want full control over the PDF, you have to generate it on the server side - that's the only way to have a verifiably correct result each time. There are many solutions for converting HTML/CSS to PDF in the backend, e.g. using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@page` selector inside of your media to set page size

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Here's the full documentation about that

If you need more examples below link can help

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_paged_media.htm

And yes you need some changes in your layout so it can fit the page

You also probably going to need `print-color-adjust: exact;`  to stop browser from ignoring your colors(it has -webkit- version for Chrome)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/print-color-adjust

Here's a documentation for this one if needed

---

There is nothing to apologize we're all here to learn from each other